# Partition the date into a weeks from a given date to the last date in the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to count the time gap between two rows for the same id if the second is less than an hour after the first, and partition the count for the week.

Suppose given date with time is `2020-07-01 08:00`

```
create table #Temp (
  Id integer not null,
  Time datetime not null
);

insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:00');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:01');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:06');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-08 09:35');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-15 16:10');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-15 16:20');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-17 06:40');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-17 06:41');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-01 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-01 09:26');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-01 10:25');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-09 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-09 09:26');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-09 10:25');
insert into #Temp  values (3, '2020-07-21 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (3, '2020-07-21 09:26');
insert into #Temp  values (3, '2020-07-21 10:25');
```

The week should extend up to the last date in the record. Here, the last date is
`2020-07-21 10:25`

Have to transform the output from this piece of code and divide the duration weekly.

```
select Id, sum(datediff(minute, Time, next_ts)) as duration_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lead(Time) over (partition by id order by Time) as next_ts
      from #Temp t
     ) t
where datediff(minute, Time, next_ts) < 60
group by Id;
```

Output:

```
id  duration_minutes
1   41
2   230
3   115
```

The desired output should divide this duration on a weekly basis,
like `Week 1`, `Week 2`, `Week 3`, and so on.

Desired Output:

If the
start date is `2020-07-01 08:00`
end date is `2020-07-21 10:25`

```
id  |   Week 1  |   Week 2  |   Week 3
--------------------------------------
1   |   30      |   0       |   11  
2   |   115     |   115     |   0
3   |   0       |   0       |   115
```

similarly, if the

start date is `2020-07-08 08:00`

```
id  |   Week 1  |   Week 2  
---------------------------
1   |   11      |   0       
2   |   115     |   0       
3   |   0       |   115
```

Comment: `2020-07-21 10:25` will be `Week 4` - if you not agree, share how week is calculated according your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select Id,
       1 + datediff(second, '2020-07-01 06:00', time) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7) as week_num,
       sum(datediff(minute, Time, next_ts)) as duration_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lead(Time) over (partition by id order by Time) as next_ts
      from Temp t
     ) t
where datediff(minute, Time, next_ts) < 60
group by Id, datediff(second, '2020-07-01 06:00', time) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)
order by id, week_num;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9bf4890ac9f7230cbb11c9c7053b5d9c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, but that week as a row.

Comment: also if the date is bigger than the activity date, the result is in minus, can we ignore that record if the date passed is greater? like in the code if we pass `2020-07-21 08:30` it will show week as negative

Comment: @AakashBashyal . . . You don't provide the desired results in the question, so the format you want is unclear.

Comment: how hard would it be to just average the duration of all the weeks rather than displaying the week_num? only two columns with `id and avg_duration`

Comment: @AakashBashyal . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Also explain how weeks are counted if there are not records for the week.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the logic behind the `week` periods. Anyone, in the example below I am using the following code to set the `week`:

```
'Week ' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, @FirstDate, next_ts) / 7)  AS VARCHAR(12))
```

You can adjust it to ignore the ours, be more precise or something else to match your real requirements.

Apart from that, you just need to perform a dynamic `PIVOT`. Here is the full working example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp;

create table #Temp (
  Id integer not null,
  Time datetime not null
);

insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:00');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:01');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:06');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-01 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-08 09:35');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-15 16:10');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-15 16:20');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-17 06:40');
insert into #Temp  values (1, '2020-07-17 06:41');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-01 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-01 09:26');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-01 10:25');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-09 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-09 09:26');
insert into #Temp  values (2, '2020-07-09 10:25');
insert into #Temp  values (3, '2020-07-21 08:30');
insert into #Temp  values (3, '2020-07-21 09:26');
insert into #Temp  values (3, '2020-07-21 10:25');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST

CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
   [ID] INT
  ,[week_day] VARCHAR(12)
  ,[time_in_minutes] BIGINT
)

DECLARE @FirstDate DATE;

SELECT  @FirstDate = MIN(Time)
FROM #Temp

INSERT INTO #TEST
select id
      ,'Week ' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, @FirstDate, next_ts) / 7)  AS VARCHAR(12))
      ,datediff(minute, Time, next_ts) 
from (select t.*,
             lead(Time) over (partition by id order by Time) as next_ts
      from #Temp t
     ) t
where datediff(minute, Time, next_ts) < 60



DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([week_day])
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT CAST(REPLACE([week_day], 'Week ', '') AS INT)
                           ,[week_day]
            FROM #TEST
        ) DS ([rowID], [week_day])
        ORDER BY [rowID]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);


DECLARE @DanymicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DanymicSQL = N'
SELECT [ID], ' + @columns + '
FROM #TEST
PIVOT
(
    SUM([time_in_minutes]) FOR [week_day] IN (' + @columns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DanymicSQL;
```

Comment: This query is working with the example I have given, but not working with the actual use case..like example there are only 10 rows when the `@FirstDate = '2020-08-02 06:00`, and in the output, it should display only `Week1`, but it is showing whole 12 weeks.

Comment: @AakashBashyal Could you share this data, too?

Comment: should I share the whole record? like all the records in the table?

Comment: @AakashBashyal No need. Can't you reproduce the issue with less records?

Comment: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/86c9cc7b66ef1c089b375d6570a95da2/DataCsv.csv,
here is the record with id and date only.

Comment: I believe you must define the definition of "week". In your example you have said week2=2020-07-08 to 2020-07-15 , this implies that a week doenst follow a 7 day pattern, but is based on certain rules. You would need to explain how you arrived that week range

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph i have updated my quetion, does that make sense now?

Comment: still doenst answer how you arrived at Week1 date range, Week2 date range etc.

Comment: that is the same, where week follows a 7-day pattern. there is no any new pattern. correct me if I am wrong in the desired output, but the week is 7 days.